# version control projects in Eclipse

Tags: version-control

Say I have Eclipse installed in office and home. Both are Eclipse version 3.5 but may have slightly difference, like plugins version. I'd like to commit the code to online repo when get off work and then checkout at home.

1. What would be a possible solution? github? sourceforge? Are they free?
2. Would those slightly difference in Eclipse cause any problem? Since I might commit whole project folder which consist some configurations.

Can the community explain a bit or suggest some keywords? I will look up more online. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of places that provide free source control hosting for open source projects.  If this is a commercial project, you will need to either host your repository yourself and make it available both in the office and from home, or use a commercial source control hosting service.

Personally I use Subversion and the wush.net subversion hosting service.  Wush has been around for a long time and are not too expensive, but a google search e.g. "subversion hosting" will turn up many other options.

Small differences in the subversion plugin version for Eclipse can cause problems.  Make sure you're using the same plugin version.  Small differences in Eclipse version should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of free SCM's available to open source projects.

If you were to choose a CVS or SVN based one, then the slight difference in your plugin versions shouldn't make a difference.

However if you were to go for one of the increasingly popular DCVS solutions such as git, mercurial or bazaar, then your local copy has a full copy of all of the history, so you could get by with creating a local repo on a memory stick making more commits at home and then synching it when your are connected to the office or the internet depending on where you decide to host your central repo.